# Are there some interface on operations in Core Fundation? not Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, core-foundation, pasteboard

I'm trying to work on carbon to cocoa. There are some carbon apis that about getting & setting   value on clipboard. All of them are in C/C++ files.

I searched many answers in the internet and apple developer website, all of them had suggest me that NSPasteboard, I also wrapp cocoa api about it in .m file and invoke them in C/C++ file, it solve me much, but not all.

PutScrapFlavor, I failed to wrap it with cocoa. Any suggestions here?

On the other hands, I really want there are some core foundation api could be called in existing C/C++ files, anyone knows this? not NSPasteboard in cocoa.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The clipboard/pasteboard is a UI concept, and the only supported UI toolkit is Cocoa. Whether or not you wish to use NSPasteboard, you have little choice in the matter.

Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

PutScrapFlavor has no exact equivalent, because there just weren’t enough distinct flavors in a four byte character code.

Instead, the new clipboard uses UTI strings in place of flavors.  Where you used to have 'TEXT' you now have `kPasteboardTypeString`, and where you used to have a private native type like 'Sp%!', you now have @"com.example.product.yourNativeFlavor".

So you're going to need a complete rewrite of your scrap handling. The good news is that the Cocoa scrap API is not very large and maps neatly onto the old Carbon API; you shouldn't find this very difficult.  And you can probably reuse all your private scrap flavors without too much trouble.

Finally -- if you're a fellow veteran of Carbon -- drag and drop interaction through the pasteboard is infinitely better than wrangling drag flavors.